# Deleting multiple row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm deleting my multiple rows in table using a `JCheckBox`. However deleting row, delete a wrong index.

```
for(int row = 0; row < tbl.getRowCount(); ++row)
{
     DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) tbl.getModel();
     Boolean ifTrue = (Boolean) tbl.getValueAt(row, 5) == true;

     if (ifTrue) 
     {
         System.out.println("Row checked " + row);
         getSelectedRows(row);
         dm.removeRow(row);
     }
     else
     {
          System.out.printf("Row %s is not checked \n", row);
     }
}

private List<Integer> getSelectedRows(int rows)
{
    List <Integer> listRows = new ArrayList();
    listRows.add(rows);

    System.out.println("Rows that deleted " +listRows);
    return listRows;
}
```

If I delete a row **0** and **6** in a range of **0 - 6**. The rows that has been deleted is **0** and **5**. 0 index was deleted first in loop and then the new rows will be **0 - 5**, so the last index will be **5** instead of **6**

Comment: What is `getSelectedRows(row)` doing?

Comment: You could change your logic to iterate the rows from highest to lowest. So that it will delete row 6 first and then row 0. That way you won't need to deal with shifting indexes

Comment: @khelwood Sorry getSelectedRows is only a method. That I retrieve using List

Comment: Why downvote???

Comment: @911DidBush Gonna try that solution. Thanks

Comment: You're returning a list from `getSelectedRows(row)`, but you don't make any use of the list. What you're doing doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @khelwood I'm gonna use it somewhere in my logic. By the way I also used that to check the rows that been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solve the problem by decrementing it starting by the highest number. Regards @911DidBush

```
for(int row = tblSchedule.getRowCount() - 1; row >= 0; row--)
{
 DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) tbl.getModel();
 Boolean ifTrue = (Boolean) tbl.getValueAt(row, 5) == true;

 if (ifTrue) 
 {
     System.out.println("Row checked " + row);
     getSelectedRows(row);
     dm.removeRow(row);
 }
 else
 {
      System.out.printf("Row %s is not checked \n", row);
 }
}
```